# display list items horizontally

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I am trying to display the items in below `ul` horizontally such that there are four items per row and they are at the centre of the screen. However, the items are still getting displayed vertically. I have tried using `display:in-line` and `display:table`. I have tried using `margin:auto` to centre the items. What am I missing ?

Here is the freemarker code where the li items are dynamically added as available :

```html
<#if realm.password && social.providers??>
  <div id="kc-social-providers" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountSectionClass!}">
    <hr/>
    <h4>${msg("identity-provider-login-label")}</h4>

    <ul id="horizontal-list" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListClass!} <#if social.providers?size gt 3>${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListGridClass!}</#if>">
      <#list social.providers as p>
        <a id="idp" id="social-${p.alias}" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListButtonClass!} <#if social.providers?size gt 3>${properties.kcFormSocialAccountGridItem!}</#if>" type="button" href="${p.loginUrl}">
          <#if p.iconClasses?has_content>
            <i class="${properties.kcCommonLogoIdP!} ${p.iconClasses!}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountNameClass!} kc-social-icon-text">${p.displayName!}</span>
            <#else>
              <span class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountNameClass!}">${p.displayName!}</span>
          </#if>
        </a>
      </#list>
    </ul>
  </div>
</#if>
```

Here is how I tried to display maximum of the four items per row as they become available:

```css
#kc-social-providers {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#horizontal-list li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: in-line;
}

#idp {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The items are still getting displayed like below:

[image]

Comment: Have you investigated CSS grid - it gives you control over how many items there should be in a row. And flex on the outer container will help you align-content center.

Comment: Typo: Not "display: in-line;", but "display: inline;", or in this case better `inline-block` actually.

Comment: I don't see any `<li>` elements in your HTML... [The documentation for Freemarker's `list` directive shows](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html) it doesn't automatically add `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `<li>` elements in your HTML... [The documentation for Freemarker's `list` directive shows](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html) it doesn't automatically add `<li>` elements.

Change your template to add those missing `<li>` elements under the `<ul>` when rendered, like so:

```
<#if realm.password && social.providers??>
  <div id="kc-social-providers" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountSectionClass!}">
    <hr/>
    <h4>${msg("identity-provider-login-label")}</h4>

    <ul id="horizontal-list" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListClass!} <#if social.providers?size gt 3>${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListGridClass!}</#if>">
    <#list social.providers as p>
        <li>
            <a id="idp" id="social-${p.alias}" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListButtonClass!} <#if social.providers?size gt 3>${properties.kcFormSocialAccountGridItem!}</#if>" type="button" href="${p.loginUrl}">
        <#if p.iconClasses?has_content>
                <i class="${properties.kcCommonLogoIdP!} ${p.iconClasses!}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountNameClass!} kc-social-icon-text">${p.displayName!}</span>
        <#else>
                  <span class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountNameClass!}">${p.displayName!}</span>
        </#if>
            </a>
        </li>
    </#list>
    </ul>
  </div>
</#if>
```

For the sake of readability, you also might want to consider pre-composing those long `class=""` attributes and other fiddly parts.

Also, you have `<a type="button">` but that's not valid HTML: the `<a type=""` attribute is for a `Content-Type` hint for downloadable links - it is *not* anything like the `<button type="">` attribute.